# Finding out how to find out the Profit/Losses average of change in this array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to find out how to get the average of change of the Profits/Losses variable

```js
var profitLosses = [867884, 984655, 322013, -69417,
  310503, 522857, 1033096, 604885, -216386, 477532,
  893810, -80353, 779806, -335203, 697845, 793163,
  485070, 584122, 62729, 668179, 899906, 834719, 132003];
```

I've used this code below to get the average, but I was wondering if there was a way to get the average of change for the period of time

```
var avg = (profitLosses / profitLosses.length) || 0;

console.log(avg)
```

Comment: what is your expected result?

Comment: *"I've used this code below to get the average"* It doesn't get the average though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume this is what you're looking for:

- First you can calculate the changes using map, and putting 0 in the first value of the array.
- Then you sum the changes using reduce.
- Then you divide by the length-1 (because there are one less changes than there are profit&losses)

Also, with this code if your changes are for example +1 then -1 the average would be 0. If you want to look at absolute changes only, you'd have to use `Math.abs(item)` in the reduce function.

```js
const profitLosses = [
  867884, 984655, 322013, -69417, 310503, 522857, 1033096, 604885, -216386,
  477532, 893810, -80353, 779806, -335203, 697845, 793163, 485070, 584122,
  62729, 668179, 899906, 834719, 132003,
];

const changes = profitLosses.map((element, index) =>
  index === 0 ? 0 : element - profitLosses[index - 1]
);

const total = profitLosses.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item, 0);
const averageChange = total / (profitLosses.length - 1);

console.log(averageChange);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Average of change is `(sum of values in Array ProfitLosses / No. of values in the array)`.

First of all : `(profitLosses / profitLosses.length)` will give you NaN , I am confused how did you got the answer.

To get the answer you need the help of Array Methods ,specifically `reduce` method. To know more about [Array Methods](https://javascript.info/array-methods).

Below is the solution to your problem using the reduce method:

`profitLosses.reduce( (sum , item) => sum += item, 0)/ profitLosses.length`

``

- `Sum` is the accumulator of the sum of array values : 11253418 (final value).
- `item` : represents each value in the array.
- `Final aeverageChange : 489279.04347826086`.